# DotVVM - CommandBinding with dynamic input parameter

Tags: dotvvm

how I can create CommandBinding to Button with dynamic input parameter in code-only component code?

In example:

```
    var btn = new Button();
    btn.SetBinding(ButtonBase.ClickProperty, GetCommandBinding(SubCategoryLoaderProperty));
```

Now I want to pass input parametr to SubCategoryLoader Command dynamically.

How?

Thanks.